# Why do the aliens in the Crystal Skull suddenly become malevolent?

Tags: indiana-jones, kingdom-of-the-crystal-skull

The aliens are portrayed as explorers and knowledge seekers. When Spalko presents the skull to them, they are grateful and offer a reward.

Why does the alien suddenly become malevolent, even doing the cliche lean into the camera sneer?

Was this just Spielberg being lazy and ripping off *Raiders of the Lost Ark* beat by beat, with the typical "greedy blond Nazi/Russian women must die"?

[image: Leaning Alien]

Comment: I can see exactly what that alien is thinking. "These humans, give them a finger, and they'll take the whole hand "

Comment: And that was not a proper reaction to villain wanting their knowledge for domination over people (or whatever she'd do with it)?

Comment: that's the problem obviously the alien would have been of this.

Comment: I'd look up a clip to try to answer this, but then I'd be watching *Crystal Skull* again and I'm not sure that's worth the rep

Answer (score 1):

The unsourced comment on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0367882/trivia?item=tr0984099) is that:

> This movie continues the Indiana Jones tradition of killing off the lead villain through paranormal means related to a consequence of the villain's own greed.

Spalko wanted all their knowledge, and she got it. Whether the aliens made a moral judgement (or even realised that she would not survive) doesn't appear to be explicitly answered.